# beg. python struggling to remove .0 at the end of an int

Tags: python

so Im taking a course intro to python and one of the labs has me stuck.

I have to take 2 inputs and divide them 3 times

ex input is
2000
2

ex output is  1000 500 250

so the input 1 is divided by input 2 then that answer is divided by output 2 again and again then print

the problem is that my output keeps putting a .0 at the end
ex 1000.0 500.0 250.0

and that is wrong when I submit it

heres what i got

```
    user_num1 = input()
    user_num2 = input()
    a = (int(user_num1) / int(user_num2))
    b = (int(a) / int(user_num2))
    c = (int(b) / int(user_num2))
    print (a, b, c)
```

Comment: What's the behavior if they don't evenly divide?

Comment: ".0 at the end of an int" - that's because it's _not_ an int - it's a floating-point number. Division like `a / b` always produces floats. If you want integer division like in C, use `a // b`.

Comment: the three examples that it runs do all evenly divide.

Comment: AHHHHHH // you got it thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused because when you divide two integers, the result is a float

```
# In your last line you can do    
print (int(a), int(b), int(c))

# Or
a = int(user_num1 / user_num2)
b = int(a / user_num2)
c = int(b / user_num2)
print (a, b, c)
```

Comment: ah i tried print int(a, b, c) and it gave me an error. i see i need int infront of each one lol thank you